# Interpolate Nulls with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to display this chart and sometimes there will be null values in each row. I've added the "interpolateNulls" to my options but it still isn't working. Is is probably an easy fix but I am stuck.

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

    data.addRows([
        [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
        [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
        [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
        [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9, null, 42.9, null],
        [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
        [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
        [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
        [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
            subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)',
        },
        interpolateNulls: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart-material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`interpolateNulls` is one of many options **not supported** by *Material* charts

*Material*: `google.charts.Line`

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

instead, recommend using a *Classic* chart, with the following option...

`theme: 'material'`

*Classic*: `google.visualization.LineChart`

Comment: ugh the material chart looks so nice though. I'll just have to write the method to do it myself I guess

Comment: Also that helps a lot. Thanks!